# In Unity, can I load a local (/Resources folder) website to safari on an ipad

Tags: unity, ios, loading, assets, file

In Unity, can I load a local (/Resources folder) website to safari on an ipad?
This works fine on a Mac, opening up a wepage from my Resources folder.

```
string path = "file://"+(Application.dataPath)+"/Resources/testsite.html";
    void OnGUI(){
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(20, 20, 100, 100), "site")){
           Application.OpenURL(path);
        }
    }
```

but when I try to load this on an iPhone or iPad, it doesn't seem to work. 
Am I accessing the address incorrectly for iOS using "file://"? 
If this is not possible, is there an alternative way I can load a locally stored website on an iOS device?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but you're using wrong folder. The Resources folder is not copied with your build; rather, it is compressed into a single file cotaining all assets from the folder.
To actually copy some files into your app, use StreamingAssets folder (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html). This folder is simply copied into resulting build, so you can use files in it like normal OS files, including, I suppose, opening them in Safari (I don't know, maybe some iOS quirks can still prevent you from doing that. It definitely works on desktop).

Answer (score 1):

According TO Unity's Manual,

Any files placed in a folder called StreamingAssets in a Unity project will be copied verbatim to a particular folder on the target machine. You can retrieve the folder using the Application.streamingAssetsPath property. For reference, the location of this folder varies per platform:

On a desktop computer (Mac OS or Windows) the location of the files can be obtained with the following code:-

```
path = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets";
```

On iOS, you should use:-

```
path = Application.dataPath + "/Raw";
```

...while on Android, you should use:-

```
path = "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/";
```

It's always best to use http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html to get the location of the StreamingAssets folder, it will always point to the correct location on the platform where the application is running.

For more information have a look into http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/StreamingAssets.html.

Answer (score 0):

You [probably] aren't going to be able to do that.

But with some Objective-C work (and I'm sure there are some easy plugins on the asset store to do this, such as [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/2738)), it should be relatively straight forward to push a [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from within the app itself with whatever html data you want.